# Unable to autofill 'Related To' from custom button URL hack

Tags: custom-button, standard-objects, tasks

I am trying to create a custom button to create a task.  I want to set the task Related To as a Campaign, but am unable to accomplish this.  What am I missing?

Button or Link URL:

```
/00T/e?{!CampaignMember.CampaignId} 
&tsk2={!CampaignMember.Contact} 
&tsk3={!CampaignMember.Campaign} 
&tsk4={!Today} 
&tsk5=Campaign Call 
&tsk12=Completed
```

I even see that this field is tsk3_mlpk, but can't pass the value of Campaign to it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The fields are ContactId and CampaignId. Also you can use the what_id and who_id parameters to set those fields. So you probably want:

```
 /00T/e?who_id={!CampaignMember.ContactId}&what_id={!CampaignMember.CampaignId}
```

You can use the Insert field picklist above the URL entry to give you the correct merge field.

Comment: That worked great, but some additional complexity is now added.  Here is what I have now:

Comment: /00T/e?who_id={!CampaignMember.ContactId}&what_id={!CampaignMember.CampaignId} 

&tsk4={!Today} 
&tsk5=Campaign Call 
&tsk12=Completed 


& IF({!CampaignMember.LeadId}==ISBLANK), 
(tsk2={!CampaignMember.Contact} && tsk3={!CampaignMember.Campaign}), 
(tsk2={!CampaignMember.Lead}& tsk3=)

Comment: What I ultimately want to do is have this button complete the related to field and Name (Contact or Lead).  It works fine with the Contact, but when trying to do this from a Lead, it still completes the related to and will not allow me to change the Contact/Lead drop down to lead and complete the name.

Comment: You can use a formula inside your who_id parameter to differentiate to a Contact or Lead
who_id={!IF(ISBLANK(CampaignMember.ContactId),CampaignMember.LeadId, CampaignMember.ContactId)} and get rid of your tsk2 and tsk3 params